# Gnuplot - Plot in one graph multiple files

Tags: regex, bash, gnuplot

I am programming in bash and I try to make a graph out of 4 files using gnuplot. 
My files contain in the first column the date and in the rest 10 columns the temperature of the ocean in various depths. I get the errors, line 0: invalid command and line 0: constant expression required.

```
MyVar="THO"         
MySeas="Annual Win Spr Aut Sum"        
MyWorkDir=/work/InterAnnual    

echo "change dir"        
cd $MyWorkDir             
MyFileArx1=0001_field_${MyVar}.grb.regular      
MyFileArx21=0021_field_${MyVar}.grb.regular    
MyFileArx25=0025_field_${MyVar}.grb.regular    
MyFileArx26=0026_field_${MyVar}.grb.regular    

for MySeasName in ${MySeas} ;do       
MyFile1=${MyFileArx1}_sm_${MySeasName}.col.dat       
MyFile21=${MyFileArx21}_sm_${MySeasName}.col.dat       
MyFile25=${MyFileArx25}_sm_${MySeasName}.col.dat       
MyFile26=${MyFileArx26}_sm_${MySeasName}.col.dat      

gnuplot << EOF       
set term postscript eps enhanced color solid        
set out 'InterAnnual.${MySeasName}.6.eps'       
set key right top            
set grid      
set xrange [ 800:2000 ]          
set size 1, 0.5        
set xlabel "year"      
set ylabel " T (C) "       
plot "${MyFile1}" u 1:11 t 'Level-6 ${MySeasName} mil0001' w l lt, \       
"${MyFile21}" u 1:11 t 'Level-6 ${MySeasName} mil0001' w l lt, \      
"${MyFile25}" u 1:11 t 'Level-6 ${MySeasName} mil0001' w l lt, \     
"${MyFile26}" u 1:11 t 'Level-6 ${MySeasName} mil0001' w l lt     
EOF              
done
```

`

Comment: bash doesn't like trailing spaces. try removing the spaces trailing after the EOF in line 31 and after the backslashs ( \ ) lines 27-30 (after the continuation backslashs in the gnuplot/plot command)

Comment: Thank you very much @Orange for your answer. I tried it, but unfortunately nothing better.

Comment: Well, for me, the error message changes to "line 0: invalid expression" when I remove the trailing spaces. The invalid expression error is because no lt is defined in spite of the keyword being present (that is, either remove lt or put the linetype you would like behind it, e.g. lt 2).

Comment: @Orange: gnuplot doesn't like characters after `\`, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script works when I add in the gnuplot part: set multiplot.
For example:

```
gnuplot << EOF    
set multiplot
```

... and then the rest of the lines.

Comment: Strange enough, because you have only a single `plot` command. Did you try @Orange's second suggestion? (`lt` needs a number)

Comment: Of course I tried it! I am trying everything from yesterday for the all day. Set multiplot is the only thing that worked. And it is strange because nowhere says this, except from a hidden example in the gnuplot manual.

Comment: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node203.html- Where says that: For some terminals, no plot is displayed until the command unset multiplot is given, which causes the entire page to be drawn and then returns gnuplot to its normal single-plot mode. For other terminals, each separate plot command produces an updated display, either by redrawing all previous ones and the newly added plot, or by just adding the new plot to the existing display.

Comment: That section has nothing to do with your actual problem... It refers to the case when you use `set multiplot`, which isn't necessary for your case. If this line makes your script work, it hides the actual problem. When running gnuplot like you do, you don't get access to the correct line number, which makes debugging more difficult. From the snippet you posted, it seems like you have spaces after the `\ ` inside the plot command. Usually, this doesn't work. Could be, that the multiplot mode changes something here. Still, using `lt` without number gives an error (although a different one)

Comment: I posted this, because this gave me the idea to put set multiplot. Also, I thought it would be nice to be shown as a comment in case that this is the problem (the: unset multiplot) for someone else. I have already said, that I corrected the spaces and aslo put lt with a number and the problem continued. For sure my script needed the corrections by @Orange but it was also necessary to put set multiplot, otherwise it did not work. I do not understand why you do not agree that this is the case, since I tried all.

Comment: I was talking about the spaces behind the backslash inside your `plot` command. If I remove those, it works fine. And this wasn't mentioned, yet (Although I guess this could be, what @sweber meant, but the bashslash got eaten up).